# How to plot multiple lines with different X indices

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, line-plot

I have 3 data frames as so:

Range is the index second Column is Number

```py
print(df1)
Range
1.27     2386.0
0.93     5598.0
1.27     3607.0
1.29     2262.0
0.94    12227.0

print(df2)
Range
1.26     6410.0
1.27     5688.0
1.25     7329.0
0.93     7757.0
1.26     2118.0
1.26     5772.0

print(df2)
Range
0.92     3368.0
1.26     4935.0
1.28     4749.0
0.94    13716.0
0.92     8478.0
1.27     7997.0
0.92    12459.0
0.92     5805.0
0.92     7842.0
1.26     8316.0
1.27    11069.0
1.27    10011.0
```

How can I plot a singe graph with the x-axis using the range and the y-axis using the second column?

I tried:

```py
df=pd.concat([df1,df2,df3], ignore_index=True, axis=1)
ax=sns.lineplot(data=df,  markers=True, dashes=False)
ax.set_title("Range vs Number")
ax.set(xlabel="Range (m)", ylabel = "Number")
plt.legend(loc='upper right', labels=['df1','df2','df3'])
plt.show()
```

But go the following error:

```
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Test DataFrames and Imports

- **Tested in `python 3.11`, `pandas 1.5.2`, `matplotlib 3.6.2`, `seaborn 0.12.1`**

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d1 = {'Range': [0.93, 0.94, 1.27, 1.29],
      'Number': [5598.0, 12227.0, 3607.0, 2262.0]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1).set_index('Range')

d2 = {'Range': [1.26, 1.27, 1.25, 0.93, 1.26, 1.26],
      'Number': [6410.0, 5688.0, 7329.0, 7757.0, 2118.0, 5772.0]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2).set_index('Range')

d3 = {'Range': [0.92, 1.26, 1.28, 0.94, 0.92, 1.27, 0.92, 0.92, 0.92, 1.26, 1.27, 1.27],
      'Number': [3368.0, 4935.0, 4749.0, 13716.0, 8478.0, 7997.0, 12459.0, 5805.0, 7842.0, 8316.0, 11069.0, 10011.0]}
df3 = pd.DataFrame(d3).set_index('Range')
```

### Combine DataFrames without an Identifying Column

```py
df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3])
```

#### `estimator='mean'`: default

- As shown in the OP. When there are multiple points for a single index, the `'mean'` is plotted and a confidence interval is shown.

```py
ax = sns.lineplot(data=df, markers=True)
```

[image]

#### `estimator=None`

- A single line with all the points shown

```py
ax = sns.lineplot(data=df, markers=True, estimator=None)
```

[image]

---

### Plot Each DataFrame in a Loop

#### `matplotlib.pyplot.plot`

```py
for i, df in enumerate([df1, df2, df3], 1):
    df = df.sort_index()  # the index must be sorted
    plt.plot(df.index, df['Number'], label=f'df{i}', marker='.')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

#### `pandas.DataFrame.plot`

- Each DataFrame can be plotted directly with `df.plot` instead of `plt.plot`, but this option requires a little more setup.

  - Create an `ax` to plot each DataFrame to, or multiple figures will be created.
  - The legend labels must be updated after creating the plot.

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i, df in enumerate([df1, df2, df3], 1):
    df = df.sort_index()
    df.plot(marker='.', ax=ax)
    
ax.legend(labels=[f'df{i}' for i in range(1, 4)])
plt.show()
```

---

### Combine DataFrames with an Identifying Column

```py
# create a single dataframe with an identifying column
df = pd.concat([df.assign(id=f'df{i}') for i, df in enumerate([df1, df2, df3], 1)])

# reset the index
df = df.reset_index()

# plot using hue to separate the lines
ax = sns.lineplot(data=df, x='Range', y='Number', hue='id', estimator=None, marker='o', hue_order=['df1', 'df2', 'df3'])
```

- Note the difference with `sns.lineplot` comparted to `plt.plot` in the loop. `seaborn` internally sorts the values for the x-axis, and the y-axis.

  - `df = df.sort_values(['Range', 'Number'])`

[image]

- Adjusting the loop to reset the index, **and** sort by the `'Range'` (the `index`) and `'Number'`.

```py
for i, df in enumerate([df1, df2, df3], 1):
    df = df.reset_index().sort_values(['Range', 'Number'])
    plt.plot('Range', 'Number', data=df, label=f'df{i}', marker='.')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]